# Update data from web service handling response delay and other errors

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, angular, rxjs

EventService component retrieves a list of items every 10000 ms

```
@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
    getEventsStream(): Observable<Event[]> {
        let url = 'event/view';
        return Observable.interval(10000).flatMap(() => {
                return this.http.get(url);
            })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return (<any>response.json()).map(item => {
                    return item;//new Event(item);
                });
            });
    }
}
```

However in this way I do not handle the case where the web service is delaying the response or is not available.

1. How can I handle this by issuing the new request 10000 ms after response has arrived?
2. How can I handle unavailability/errors from the web service by issuing a new request 30000 ms after this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `retry` operator for this:

```
return Observable.interval(10000).flatMap(() => {
         return this.http.get(url);
       })
       .retryWhen(error => error.delay(30000)) // <----
       .map((response: Response) => {
          return (<any>response.json()).map(item => {
             return item;//new Event(item);
          });
       });
```

See these articles for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/04/18/interacting-efficiently-with-a-restful-service-with-angular2-and-rxjs-part-3/
- https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html

Comment: OK thanks, I'll try.If the web service response is very delayed how can I handle this fact by issuing the new one **only after** response has arrived?

Comment: I reworked the code using the retryWhen you suggested. does the proposed solution seem correct to you? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this way it works:

```
let obs;
return Observable
    .create((o) => {
        obs = o;
        obs.next();
    })
    .flatMap(() => {
        //console.log("executing request");
        return this.http.get(url);
    })
    .retryWhen(error => error.delay(30000))
    .map((response: Response) => {
        //console.log("response received");
        setTimeout(() => {
            //console.log("pushing next");
            obs.next();
        }, 10000);
        return (<any>response.json()).map(item => {
            return item;//new Event(item);
        });
    });
```

does this seems a correct solution?